# ¿Como invertir el orden de un chat en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, css, php5

¿Como puedo lograr que los mensajes mas recientes estén en la parte de arriba y los mensajes mas antiguos en la parte de abajo, los mensajes se guardan en mi base de datos.

Este es mi chat.php: dentro esta el estilo y un script que actualiza el load.php

```
<style>
*{margin:0px; padding:0px;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
#logout{width:60px; height:20px; position:absolute; top:6px; right:20px;
margin-bottom:40px; text-align:center; color:#fff}
#container{width:75%; height:auto; position:relative; top:8px; margin:auto;}
```

`#session-name{width:100%; height:36px; margin-bottom:30px; font-size:20px}`
`.session-text{width:300px; height:30px;padding:6px 10px;margin: 8px 0;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 4px;box-sizing: border-box; font-size:24px}`

`#result-wrapper{width:100%; margin:auto; height:450px;}`
`#result{height:450px; overflow:scroll;overflow-x: hidden;}`

`#form-container{width:100%; margin:auto; height:80px;}`
`.form-text{float:left; width:85%; height:80px;}`
`#comment{width:100%; height:79px; resize:none;}`
`.form-btn{float:left; width:15%; height:80px;}`
`#btn{border:none; height:80px; width:100%; background:tomato; color:#fff; font-size:22px}`

`.chats{width:100%; margin-bottom:6px;}`
`.chats strong{color:#6d84b4}`
`.chats p{ font-size:14px; color:#aaa; margin-right:10px}`
`</style>`

`<script>`
 `function autoRefresh_div()`
 `{`
      `$("#result").load("load.php").show();`
  `}`
  `setInterval('autoRefresh_div()', 2000);`
`</script>`

Este es mi archivo load.php:

```
  <?php
  include("config.php");
  session_start();
  $comm = mysql_query("select name,comment,post_time from comments");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($comm)){
    $name=$row['name'];
    $comment=$row['comment'];
      $time=$row['post_time'];
  ?>
  <div class="chats"><strong><?=$name?>:</strong> <?=$comment?> <p style="float:right"><?=date("j/m/Y g:i:sa", strtotime($time))?></p></div>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intentalo asi:

```
<?php
  include("config.php");
  session_start();
  $comm = mysql_query("select name,comment,post_time from comments order by post_time desc");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($comm)){
    $name=$row['name'];
    $comment=$row['comment'];
      $time=$row['post_time'];
  ?>
  <div class="chats"><strong><?=$name?>:</strong> <?=$comment?> <p style="float:right"><?=date("j/m/Y g:i:sa", strtotime($time))?></p></div>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Si funciona perfecto, ¿Como haria para que solo muestre los ultimos 10 mensajes?

Comment: Yo mismo me respondere :D. Agregando LIMIT 10

Comment: Correcto @LuisCesar